# NetLogo - finding patch with max value

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to have female animal agents select all patches that have no females within a certain radius. Then, from among those patches, I'd like the female to move to the one which has the highest average prey within the same radius. I currently have:

```
  let potential-sites patches with [not any? patches in-radius 2 with [owner-fem != nobody]]
  let pot-site-areas [patches in-radius 2] of potential-sites
  let pot-site-prey map [mean [prey] of ?] pot-site-areas
  let ideal-site max pot-site-prey
```

But then I realize that I have no way to tell the female which patch to go to, because ideal-site is just a value with no patch coordinates associated with it. Any suggestions on how to link the value to the actual patch? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `max-one-of`, perhaps like this:

```
let ideal-site max-one-of potential-sites [mean [prey] of patches in-radius 2]
```

Comment: this is really clean. I didn't know that `max-one-of` could work like that. Cool! Does this process include the `potential-site` in the calculation of mean?

Comment: Yes: that's how `in-radius` works.  If you don't want that you can replace `patches` with `other patches`.